# Synthesisablity of using the index of an outer loop as variable limit for a nested inner loop?

Tags: vhdl

Can I get synthesizable VHDL if I use the index of an outer loop as variable limit for a nested inner loop? For example:
Is the following code synthesizable VHDL?

```
 a: for i3 in 0 to 5 loop
            b: for j3 in 0 to i3 loop
            sum2(i3,j3)<=ZERO
            end loop b;
        end loop a;
```

where sum2 is a bidimensional array of std_logic and ZERO is a constant that represents '0'

Comment: It depends on what how you used those loop variables. And what's described inside. The rule of looping is quite simple: Can you deduce the number of iterations before compilation or not? It should be a fixed number. Because you can't have an 'infinite' hardware or 'run-time changing' hardware......

Comment: Yes, the outter loop has 6 itterations. The inner loop has:
- 1 itteration for the 0-th iteration of the outer loop
- 2 itterations for the 1-st iteration of the outer loop
- 3 itterations for the 2-nd iteration of the outer loop
....
- 6 iterations for the 6th iteration of outer loop.

Is this enough so that my VHDL code is synthesizable?

I would just place an assignment inside. For example:
sum2(i3,j3)<=ZERO where sum2 is a bidimensional array of std_logic and ZERO is a constant that represents '0'.

Comment: @MituRaj  It's not that easy any more. E.g. Synplify is actually able to synthesize a (correct!) netlist out of a loop with variable length in some cases.

Comment: That might be tool dependent and hence such a code is not portable. The OP's question is on generic RTL design.

Comment: Synthesisable. Some tools may have difficulty with it : in that case there's a dead easy transformation that works : loop j over the full range, and embed the loop body in an `if j <= i` statement.

Answer (score 3):

The number of iterations of the loops `i3` and `j3` in your example code can be predetermined by a Synthesiser. The loops will be unrolled by the Synthesiser to a fixed number of assignment statements on `sum2`. So yes, this particular example is synthesisable.